# For or Foreach for this request result?

Tags: laravel, for-loop, foreach

Returning mi Laravel request I got his for an anwser:

```
{
"_method": "POST",
"_token": null,
"nome": "AUTO ESCOLA GUILHERMITTI & LOBANCO LTDA",
"cnpj": "00635344000177",
"novoSegmento": null,
"natureza": "206-2",
"total": "49993",
"socio-0": "ELIANA CRISTINA GUILHERMITTI RODRIGUES  49-Sócio-Administrador",
"socio-1": "SUZANA MARQUES LOBANCO  49-Sócio-Administrador",
"socio-2": "AMARILDO APARECIDO RODRIGUES  49-Sócio-Administrador",
"socio-3": "VALDEMIR FRANCISCO DA COSTA  22-Sócio",
"socio-4": "ANDRE LUIS LOBANCO  49-Sócio-Administrador",
"nomeFantasia": null,
"IE": null,
"logradouro": null,
"numero": "1408",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": null,
"uf": "SP",
"cidade": "Bady Bassitt",
"ddd": null,
"telefone": null,
"ddd1": null,
"celular": null,
"receita1": "0.00",
"referenciaClientes": [
{
"nome": null
},
{
"ddd": null
},
{
"telefone": null
},
{
"ramal": null
},
{
"endereco": null
},
{
"bairro": null
},
{
"uf": null
},
{
"cidade": null
},
{
"cep": null
},
{
"email": null
}
],
"BancoreferenciaClientes": [
{
"contato": null
}
],
"referenciaCLientes": [
{
"complento": null
}
],
"banco": null,
"agencia": null,
"contaCorrente": null,
"bancoContato": null,
"telefoneBanco": null,
"cidadeBanco": null,
"imoveis": [
{
"enderecoBem": null
},
{
"areaBem": null
},
{
"valorBem": "0.00"
},
{
"cidadeBem": null
}
],
"aceite": "1"
}
```

I need to save all items, but don´t know how to deal right with `socio-*`. It is variable and I´ll never know hao many times it will occur.

I am a little lost on how to handle this...
I thought I should get how many times 'socio' occurs using:

```
$s = substr_count($request, 'socio');
```

Now I must save it a json, like:

```
    socio-0{
    nome: "ELIANA CRISTINA GUILHERMITTI RODRIGUES",
    qual: "49-Sócio-Administrador"
    },
```

Comment: That looks like json formatting. Try [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and a `foreach` should be nice

Comment: Do you just need the count

Comment: If you post the full response payload we might be able to help you a little better. If you only need a count, explode it on colons or something and wrap that in `sizeof()`

Answer (score 1):

I hope your data format is **Json** so first change as **array** then use **foreach**

```
$array_data = json_decode($json,true);

$data = [];
foreach($array_data as $key => $value)
{
   // first we are checking key should be not array and then socio- is exists
   if(!is_array($key) && strpos($key, 'socio-') !== false)
   {
      $number = substr($value, strlen('socio-'));
      $data[$number] = $value;
   }
}
dd($data);
```

so you will get response like this

```
[
 0 =>'ELIANA CRISTINA GUILHERMITTI RODRIGUES',
 1 =>'SUZANA MARQUES LOBANCO',
 2 =>'AMARILDO APARECIDO RODRIGUES',
 3 =>'VALDEMIR FRANCISCO DA COSTA',
 4 =>'ANDRE LUIS LOBANCO',
];
```

Comment: Can I change it back to json with json_encode and save it?

Comment: yes you can do it ryt ? or you want save all data again ?

Comment: I want to save it as json on a database field

Comment: array to json u can use json_encode and save it ryt ?

Comment: try and if you think this answer helped you mark as answer

Comment: I´ve edited the question to show more of what I want!

Comment: 49 ,22 numbers are random numbers ?